# PHP filter through array of objects and return new array of objects, while removing duplicates based on one property

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, api, filter

I have this array of 8k or so objects that all have a property `phase`, and I am attempting to filter out duplicate phases. I was trying with `array_unique`, but I can't seem to get that right. Here's a snippet of the object:

```
array [
0 => {#525
    "street_address1": "Some St. 1"
    "street_address2": null
    "phase": "101"
    "sales_rep": "164"
    "id": "abd90d6b-28a8-2be6-d6c1-abd9007aef38"
    "name": "48TH ST E"
    "block_minimum": 400
    "block_maximum": 498
    "side": 2
  }
  1 => {#527
    "street_address1": "Some St. 2"
    "street_address2": null
    "phase": "101"
    "sales_rep": "164"
    "id": "abd90d6b-28a8-2be6-d6c1-abd9007aef38"
    "name": "48TH ST E"
    "block_minimum": 401
    "block_maximum": 499
    "side": 1
  }
  2 => {#580
    "street_address1": "Some St. 3"
    "street_address2": null
    "phase": "103"
    "sales_rep": "164"
    "id": "a1d58c9c-6ba7-ebc6-8a74-a1d5806e0bcf"
    "name": "11TH AVE S"
    "block_minimum": 4700
    "block_maximum": 4798
    "side": 2
  }
  3 => {#528
    "street_address1": "Some St. 4"
    "street_address2": null
    "phase": "103"
    "sales_rep": "164"
    "id": "a1d58c9c-6ba7-ebc6-8a74-a1d5806e0bcf"
    "name": "11TH AVE S"
    "block_minimum": 4700
    "block_maximum": 4798
    "side": 2
  }
]
```

This would be for a backend api GET return. I have a method that gets all of the addresses from the database and then needs to filter through and only return unique phases. I'll also add that I'm using Laravel 5.4, though I didn't see any helpers that might assist me.

Comment: do you use Eloquent? And if it finds multiple addresses with the same phrase, is it important which one will be returned?

Comment: I am using eloquent, though this particularly method is a raw query. It's not important, as I'm only trying to list all of the unique phases based a particular id, which is already applied.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-unique , this seems to be what you need to filter if you can't do it in the query builder. It is more effective if you can do it during the query builder though, since you don't need to handle those 8k lines.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I got this to work and it suits me perfectly. Thanks everyone!

```
$phases = array();
    foreach ($salesRepAddresses as $address) {
        $phases[] = $address->phase;
    }
    $uniquePhases = array_unique($phases);

    return $uniquePhases;
```

Comment: ah, I guess i misread your question then. I thought you wanted to return adresses, but none of them should have the same phase. Well, at least I was helpful by making the array_unique function known to you. ;)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `array_column` to collect all phases then `array_unique`

try this:

```
$phases = array_column($array, 'phase');
$uniquePhases = array_unique($phases);
```

Comment: This is returning an empty array.

Comment: @MattLarson which one `$phases` or `$uniquePhases` ?

Comment: $phases is empty and then $uniquePhases is obviously empty as well. Maybe it's the way the objects are nested?

Comment: or maybe you should load your addresses into the `$array` variable ;)

Comment: But on a more serious note, this solution is not going to get you anywhere, it does not apply to your question at all ..

Comment: I did load the addresses into the $array variable hah

Answer (score 0):

In the comment section of the [php.net manual for array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) there is an example for exactly what you want. If you don't understand it, or it doesn't work, ask away ;)

---

> Create multidimensional array unique for any single key index.  e.g I
>   want to create multi dimentional unique array for specific code
>
> Code :  My array is like this,

```
<?php 
$details = array( 
    0 => array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"Mike",    "num"=>"9876543210"), 
    1 => array("id"=>"2", "name"=>"Carissa", "num"=>"08548596258"), 
    2 => array("id"=>"1", "name"=>"Mathew",  "num"=>"784581254"), 
); 
?>
```

> You can make it unique for any field like id, name or num.
>
> I have develop this function for same :

```
<?php 
function unique_multidim_array($array, $key) { 
    $temp_array = array(); 
    $i = 0; 
    $key_array = array(); 

    foreach($array as $val) { 
        if (!in_array($val[$key], $key_array)) { 
            $key_array[$i] = $val[$key]; 
            $temp_array[$i] = $val; 
        } 
        $i++; 
    } 
    return $temp_array; 
} 
?>
```

> Now, call this function anywhere from your code,
>
> something like this,

```
<?php 
$details = unique_multidim_array($details,'id'); 
?>
```